# jquery cant append a string to an object

Tags: jquery

what I want to do is:

Wrap a link around `$feedbodyimage.eq(0)`, then append the whole thing into `$feedbodycontainer`.

But it is not working. The output is `[object object]`.

Please help

```
var $feedbodycontainer = $("<div class='feedbody'></div>");
var $feedbodyimage = $feedbody.find("img");

    if($feedbodyimage.length) {

        $feedbodycontainer.append($feedbodyimage.eq(0));// it works
             //$feedbodycontainer.append("<a href='"+feedlink+"' target='_blank'>"+$feedbodyimage.eq(0)+"</a>";) // it doen't work. output is [object object] hyperlinked.

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as a separate answer.

My other answer shows the problem and a workaround, but really you should be doing it differently from the start.

```
var $feedbodycontainer = $("<div class='feedbody'></div>");
var $feedbodyimage = $feedbody.find("img");

if($feedbodyimage.length) {

      // Create the <a> element, append the <img> to the <a>, 
      //   and append the <a> to the container.
   $("<a>",{href:feedlink, target:"_blank"})
       .append($feedbodyimage.eq(0))
       .appendTo($feedbodycontainer);
}
```

If you wanted a copy of the image instead of the original, change this...

```
.append($feedbodyimage.eq(0))
```

to this...

```
.append($feedbodyimage.eq(0).clone(true))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because a jQuery object is not HTML, and a native DOM element is not HTML.

HTML is HTML. So if you wanted to concatenate it in, you'd need to get it as HTML.

```
var HTML = $feedbodyimage[0].outerHTML;

$feedbodycontainer.append("<a href='"+feedlink+"' target='_blank'>"+ HTML +"</a>");
```

So `[0]` gets the native DOM element at index `0`, and `outerHTML` renders it and its content as an HTML string.

---

Note that `.outerHTML` isn't supported by FireFox, but support is coming.

Here's a possible patch for `outerHTML`...

```
function outerHTML( el ) {
    return el.outerHTML || 
           document.createElement('div')
                   .appendChild(el.cloneNode(true)) 
                   .parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

...to which you would pass a DOM element, and it would return the HTML string...

```
var HTML = outerHTML( $feedbodyimage[0] );
```

Comment: i need to have it to run in FF as well tho. Is there a work around?

Comment: @Shadow_boi: I added an `outerHTML` function that would serve as a patch.

Comment: @Shadow_boi: There's a better solution than using HTML though. I'll add a separate answer for that

Answer (score 0):

While building the html string you should use the `html` method to get its `html`. Since `html` method will give the inner html you should get the outer html. OuterHTML is not supported by all the browser so there is a work around to it. Try this

```
var html = ($feedbodyimage.get(0).outerHTML || 
             $feedbodyimage.eq(0).clone(true).wrap('<div />').parent().html());

$feedbodycontainer.append("<a href='" + feedlink + "' target='_blank'>" 
        + html +"</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `wrap` function something like this:

```
$feedbodyimage.eq(0).wrap('<a href="your_location" />').parent().appendTo($feedbodycontainer);
```

Try this fiddle here showing it working http://jsfiddle.net/BLsFz/